# Prepopulating check box in Gravity Forms based on other field data

Tags: checkbox, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Im trying to prepopulate a checkbox based on whether a condition in another field within the same form is true.

here's the code i managed to pull together looking at various examples around the web.  It would seem that my IF statment to update the choice is wonky, but I don't have sufficient syntax knowledge to correct it.  Can you help?

```
    add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_19', 'Cover_needed' );
function Cover_needed( $form ){

        $VAR_Family_Home = $form_data['field'][2];
        $VAR_Life_Style = $form_data['field'][3];
        $VAR_Debt = $form_data['field'][4];

        if( 1 === $field->id ) {

            foreach( $field->choices as &$choice ){

                if ($VAR_Family_Home < 3  'familyhome' === $choice['value'] || $VAR_Life_Style < 3  'lifestyle' === $choice['value'] || $VAR_Debt < 3  'debt' === $choice['value']){
                    $choice['isSelected'] = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
    return $form;
}
```

Thanks in advance
Stuart